# Android Studio: How do I get a button in main activity to do something in a fragment when they aren't directly connected?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So I guess they could be directly connected, but I'm unsure how I'd access the fragments method's from the main activity in this situation.

I'm using a navigation bar on the main activity and I'd like a button in the nav bar to do an action inside of one of the fragments connected to the navigation bar. Is there anyway I could do this?

Comment: Use listener and callback to activity

Comment: What type of listener/how should I setup the listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Fragment, create a interface and setter.

```
    private lateinit var listener: YourFragmentListener

    interface YourFragmentListener {

        fun doSomething()
    }

    fun setListener(listener: YourFragmentListener){

        this.listener = listener
    }
```

Make your Activity implements the listener

```
    class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity(), YourFragmentListener {

       override fun doSomething(){

         //do what you want
       }
    }
```

when you create the fragment, also set the listener.

```
   val fragment = YourFragment()
   fragment.setListener(this)
```

finally, in your fragment, you can use listener everywhere to callback to activity

```
  listener.doSomething()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure if I ever have a reference to the fragment, This is how I get the fragment to display:  

switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentHolder,
                        new Fragment1()).commit();
               
                break;

Comment: @DoctorArnold itˊs the same idea. `Fragment fragment = new Fragment1()` `fragment.setListener(this)`

Comment: Gotcha. It looks like you're using Kotlin, but I'm using java so what does this line do: private lateinit var listener: YourFragmentListener ?

Comment: @DoctorArnold equals to `private YourFragmentListener listener;` in Java

Comment: Final question which is similar to last as this really should work. When I start a new fragment by using a new statment, wouldn't that be a different instance of the one created in the line I posted in my first reply?

Comment: @DoctorArnold If you use `replace` method to switch fragment, it will create new instance every time. So it is equivalent